Как правильно изменять размер окна в winapi
Я пытаюсь сделать изменение размера окна, как со стилем WS_OVERLAPPED, используя WS_POPUP. С правой стороной все получилось, а вот с левой проблемы. Не могу понять почему когда я тяну левый край окна, курсор мыши находится дальше чем край окна, за который я тяну. При этом окно по краям начинает мерцать, а кнопки в не клиентской области как будто одновременно находятся в двух положениях. А если тянуть правый край, то сам край движется прям за курсором( как изменять размер папки в видновс ). Не пойму где проблема, в расчётах новой ширины окна или позиции, или вообще в другом месте кода.
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
        if (dragging) 
        {
            POINT currentPoint = { GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam) };
            GetCursorPos(&currentPoint);
            ScreenToClient(hwnd, &currentPoint);

            // Смещение для ПРАВОЙ СТОРОНЫ ОКНА
            int deltaXRight = currentPoint.x - startPoint.x;
            // Новая ширина ПРАВОЙ СТОРОНЫ ОКНА
            int newWidth = startRect.right - startRect.left + deltaXRight;

            // Может я не правильно делаю рассчет
            // Смещение для Левой СТОРОНЫ ОКНА
            int deltaXLeft = startPoint.x - currentPoint.x;
            // Новая ширина ЛЕВОЙ СТОРОНЫ ОКНА
            int newWidthLeft = startRect.right - startRect.left - deltaXRight;
            // Новая позиция левой стороны
            int newCurrentWidthLeft = startRect.left + deltaXRight;

            if (startPoint.x > startRect.right - startRect.left - BORDERWIDTH)
            {
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, 0, 0, newWidth, startRect.bottom - startRect.top, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOMOVE);
            }
            else if (startPoint.x < BORDERWIDTH && newWidthLeft > MIN_WIDTH)
            {
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, newCurrentWidthLeft, startRect.top, newWidthLeft, startRect.bottom - startRect.top, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
            }
        }
        break;
    }

Остальной код
        case WM_NCHITTEST: 
    {
        POINT pt = { GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam) };
        ScreenToClient(hwnd, &pt);

        RECT closeButton = GetCloseButtonRect(hwnd);
        RECT maximizeButton = GetMaximizeButtonRect(hwnd);
        RECT minimizeButton = GetMinimizeButtonRect(hwnd);

        if (PtInRect(&closeButton, pt)) {
            return HTCLOSE;
        }
        else if (PtInRect(&maximizeButton, pt)) {
            return HTMAXBUTTON;
        }
        else if (PtInRect(&minimizeButton, pt)) {
            return HTMINBUTTON;
        }
        // Если курсор в заголовке, возвращаем HTCAPTION
        if (pt.y < GetTitleBarHeight()) {
            return HTCAPTION; // Указываем, что курсор в заголовке
        }

        LRESULT hit = DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        if (hit == HTCLIENT) {

            RECT rc;
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
            if (pt.x > rc.right - 10) {
                return HTRIGHT; // Правый край
            }
            else if (pt.x < 10) {
                return HTLEFT; // Левый край
            }
        }
        return hit;
    }
    case WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN:
    { 
        POINT pt = { GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam) };
        ScreenToClient(hwnd, &pt);

        RECT closeButton = GetCloseButtonRect(hwnd);
        RECT maximizeButton = GetMaximizeButtonRect(hwnd);
        RECT minimizeButton = GetMinimizeButtonRect(hwnd);

        if (PtInRect(&closeButton, pt)) {
            PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
        }
        if (PtInRect(&maximizeButton, pt)) {
            ShowWindow(hwnd, IsZoomed(hwnd) ? SW_RESTORE : SW_MAXIMIZE);
        }
        if (PtInRect(&minimizeButton, pt)) {
            SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MINIMIZE, 0);
        }
        if (pt.y < GetTitleBarHeight()) {
            // Начинаем перетаскивание окна
            PostMessage(hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MOVE | HTCAPTION, lParam);
            return HTCAPTION;
        }
        dragging = true;
        startPoint.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
        startPoint.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, &startRect);
        ScreenToClient(hwnd, &startPoint);
        
        SetCapture(hwnd); // Захватываем мышь

        return 0;
    }

    case WM_LBUTTONUP: {
        // Остановка изменения размера окна при отпускании левой кнопки мыши
        if (dragging) {
            dragging = false;
            ReleaseCapture(); // Освобождаем мышь
        }
        break;
    }



Мне представляется, что определять, за какой край окно тянется, следует в обработчике WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN. Флажек какой-нибудь выставлять. Нет необходимости переводить все координаты в оконные.
